# System.InvalidOperationException on new PdfDocument(PdfReader)

Tags: itext7

My co-worker generated this [PDF file](http://www.filedropper.com/ls2x1).

When I try to open it using new PdfDocument(PdfReader), I'm getting this Exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException:
Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
    HResult: -2146233079
    HelpLink: null
    InnerException: null
    Message: "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute."
    Source: "mscorlib"
    StackTrace: "   at System.Collections.ArrayList.ArrayListEnumeratorSimple.MoveNext()\r\n   at iText.Kernel.XMP.Impl.XMPNormalizer.MoveExplicitAliases(XMPNode tree, ParseOptions options)\r\n   at iText.Kernel.XMP.Impl.XMPNormalizer.Process(XMPMetaImpl xmp, ParseOptions options)\r\n   at iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument.Open(PdfVersion newPdfVersion)..."
```

I'm running iText under .Net Framework 4.8

It must be related to some formatting of the pdf, but I can open it without issues in Adobe Reader and in my browser.  Any help appreciated.

Comment: the link to the PDF doesn't work: could you update it?

Comment: Yeah try it now

Comment: Which iText version do you use? I wasn't able to reproduce it on the latest one: 7.1.15

Comment: I'm also using v7.1.15

Comment: This looks like a potential bug (probably .NET framework-dependent). Some XMP metadata parsing-related changes (with a switch to primarily lazy mode) have been introduced in 7.1.16-SNAPSHOT, can you check if the result is different in 7.1.16-SNAPSHOT?

Comment: This still occurs on iText 7.2, but not for every PDF document. Same callstack, XMPNormalizer.MoveExplicitAliases is the culprit.